# My jquery script only works in Firefox, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">dv1</div>
    <div id="div2">dv2</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getData(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"j.json",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(jsondata){
                output(jsondata);               
            }
        });
    }

    function output(json){

        //var Data = eval('(' + json + ')');
        var html = '';
        //alert(Data.length);
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            html += ' name:' + json[i].name + ' age:' + json[i].age;
        }

        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = html;
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = json[0].name;
    }

    setTimeout(getData, 3000);      

    </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

j.json file is

```
[{"name":"aaa","age":18},{"name":"bbb","age":19}]
```

The aim of above code is to update div content with data in local json file. I've tried that in IE & Chrome, but neither worked. I've googled a lot but still can't figure it out.

Anyone got any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting that AJAX call in Chrome's developer tools?

Comment: It says "Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." & "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/austin/Documents/work/j.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use web server?

AJAX calls doesnt work with URL starting with `file://`. This because of the same-origin requirements which were instituted to help deal with cross-site scripting (XSS). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) for more details.

And as I noticed, you should use `$(document).ready(function(){ your code })` instead of `setTimeout(getData, 3000);`

Comment: So how to deal with local file?

Comment: Install a web server :)

Comment: @Austin, I'm pretty sure you can't do this with a local file.

Comment: If it works in firefox, it will probably works with web server crossbrowser. starting with http://

Comment: If my answer solve your problem please mark it as answer - its not easy to gain some reputation :)